# Two scroll windows

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I currently have something very similar to this project:

http://codepen.io/dmastag/pen/oXORpZ

but additionally, the window on the right contains tabs (md-tabs) so that on click you switch windows which have their own scrolls. Problem is, I cannot use scroll function on the right window, only on the left one. Any idea how to solve that? My goal is to extend the list in the right window when the scroll is at the very bottom of the list.

I tried to get the selector md-tab-content, because I suspected that its the window with the scroll, however it says that its value is null?! Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any other solutions to solve this problem? I will be greatful.

The DOM tree looks like this in the browser:

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tabs-wrapper>
        <md-tabs-content-wrapper>
            <md-tab-content>
            </md-tab-content>
        </md-tabs-content-wrapper>
    </md-tabs-wrapper>
</md-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a plnkr or codepen with your code ? Did you tried something like:

```
md-tabs-wrapper{ 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    background-color: rgb(68, 114, 196) !important; 
    z-index: 1000; 
    width: 100%; 
}

md-tabs.md-dynamic-height md-tabs-content-wrapper { 
    top: 48px !important; 
}
```